# RACCommand Confusion

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I'm attempting to use `RACCommand` on my PasswordResetViewController. In my `viewDidLoad` I have the following:

```
sendButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Reset Password", style: .Done, target: self, action: nil)

var emailIsValid = textField.rac_textSignal().map { text -> AnyObject! in
    return count((text as! String)) > 0
}

let passwordResetSignal = RACSignal.createSignal { (subscriber) -> RACDisposable! in
    User.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground(self.textField.text) { success, error in
        if success {
            subscriber.sendNext(success)
            subscriber.sendCompleted()
        } else {
            subscriber.sendError(error)
        }
    }

    return nil
}

sendButtonItem.rac_command = RACCommand(enabled: emailIsValid) { (input) in
    return passwordResetSignal
}

sendButtonItem.rac_command.executionSignals.subscribeError { (error) -> Void in
    println("ERROR!")
}

sendButtonItem.rac_command.executionSignals.subscribeNext { (success) -> Void in
    println("SUCCESS!")
}

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = sendButtonItem
```

The `rightBarButtonItem` enables/disables as I expect but I'm not getting any next or error events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `executionSignals` is a *signal of signals*. In other words: each time the command is executed, it sends command's *signal* (in your case, `passwordResetSignal`) as its next value.

If you want to subscribe for values sent from the `passwordResetSignal`, use `switchToLatest`:

```
sendButtonItem.rac_command.executionSignals.switchToLatest().subscribeNext { (success) -> Void in
    println("SUCCESS!")
}
```

There is a separate signal `errors` in `RACCommand` which can be used to subscribe errors received from the execution signal (note: the errors are sent as `next` values):

```
sendButtonItem.rac_command.errors.subscribeNext { (error) -> Void in
    println("ERROR!")
}
```